# Linear Algebra - Pseudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

[image]

This is the solution for the problem: find an explicit formula for the following expression for
$T^{+}(z_1,z_2)$, where $T$ is the linear transformation.

$T: \Bbb{C}^2 \longrightarrow  \Bbb{C}^2$ defined by, $T(z_1, z_2) = ((1-i)z_2, (1+i)z_1+z_2)$

I get the part where pseudoinverse of $u_1$ and $u_2$ is as shown before. But I really don't get how this solution got the part about expressing $(z_1, z_2)$ with $u_1, u_2$.
Could anyone please shed some light about this part?